# Is this a measurable function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\Omega_1 = \{ a, b, c, d \}$ and $Ω_2 = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$ , and assume $F_i = \mathcal P ( \Omega_i ) ,\space i=1,2$.
Consider a uniform probability assignment over $\Omega_1$ . For the map $X(a)=1, X(b)=2, X(c)=3, X(d)=4$, find $X^{-1} ({ 5 })$; is it in $F_1$ ? Is $X$ measurabe w.r.t $(F_1,F_2)$?

Another problem I am facing is that is the inverse image defined in a way similar to that of algebric functions i.e. if $f(A)=B$, then is it necessary to have $f^{-1}(B)=A$? I am having this doubt because the standard definition never ensures that the inverse map has to be in line with the map we defined.

A bit more clarification about this part of question. Let us consider the above example itself. In this case how will we define $X^{-1}$? Can we have $X^{-1}(1) = X^{-1}(2) = X^{-1}(3) = X^{-1}(4) = X^{-1}(5) = a$? I have this confusion because the definition states the relation as follows - nowhere is here any mention of $X^{-1} \circ X=\mathbb {id}$ (the identity relation) - : 
let $(X, \Sigma)$ and $(Y, T)$ be measurable spaces, meaning that $X$ and $Y$ are sets equipped with respective sigma algebras $Σ$ and $Τ$. A function $f: X \to Y$ is said to be measurable if the preimage of $E$ under $f$ is in $Σ$ for every $E \in Τ$, i.e. $f^{-1}(E) := \{ x\in X |\; f(x) \in E \} \in \Sigma,\;\;  \forall E \in T$.

Comment: If $F_i$ meant to be the $\sigma$-field generated by $\Omega_i$? If so, then $F_i = 2^{\Omega_i}$ (power set) above and hence any function is measurable.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, tha's right. Are you cocluding that Fi=2^(Ωi) because I have defined it to be P(Ωi)? Also, could you please answer the second part.

Comment: Please note that I have reformatted your question in LaTeX. In the future, if you don't do it yourself, don't be surprised that you don't get any answer! Mathematical formulae written in LaTeX are much easier (and much more pleasant) to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a severe mistake here: you assume that $X^{-1}$ is the inverse map of $X$. It is not, since $X$ is not necessarily invertible. We define $X^{-1}(E)$ the way you write it yourself, but we do not necessarily define $X^{-1}$ unless $X$ is invertible.

In your example, ask yourself: what are the elements of $\Omega_1$ that are mapped to $5$ through $X$? Nobody, of course, therefore $X^{-1}(5) = \emptyset$.

Comment: But what will $X^{−1}(4,5)$ map to? Will it map to {$ {d, \emptyset}$} or {d} alone.

Comment: @Madhusudana: $X^{-1}(\{4,5\}) = X^{-1}(\{4\}) \cup X^{-1}(\{5\}) = \{d\} \cup \emptyset = \{d\}$.